# Pixel Manipulation with C++

Tags: c++, pixel

I want to take an image in `jpg` format, split it up in pixels and then manipulate those pixels (duplicate them, change their position etc..)

Of course I'm not asking for the code :-) but the tools to do it. I am newbie in programming.

I know nothing about reading from an image, manipulating and outputing it. Do I need special libraries to import? Special commands to use in order to manipulate the image?

What I want to do is experiment with zooming a `jpg` to infinity by manipulating the number and position of pixels.

Comment: .jpg requires decompression. Why not .bmp?

Comment: Why not? :-D By the way, why can't we enlarge any image by simply taking each row of pixels and doubling it? a newbie's naïveté should be treated with respect... :)

Comment: @user1101080: Well you *can*, it will simply be skewed along the vertical as you are not also doubling the horizontal.  A naive enlarging algorithm could turn each pixel into four identical pixels, it would just look like crap.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure to read the FAQ to find your way around. I edited your post to have more focus and less noise. I hope the changes are alright.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Comment: hehe I'm sure it would Ed S. but how about encircling each pixel with 8 identical ones? Wish I could try it right now and find out how crap that would look right away!

Comment: That's ok pmr, thanks for the link Pubby and for directing me to ImageMagick Antti, sorry for being lazy and not realizing there were similar questions with ImageMagick suggestions about them...

Comment: Edits by @pmr seem to make the question less vague.  Voting to reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CImg Library](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html), Also you might find something on [this](http://www.freeprogrammingresources.com/imglib.html) list

Comment: Both links dead, any new material?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few libraries that can be used for manipulating images. I recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (see [documentation for the C++ interface](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php)), but there's also [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/).

Using ImageMagick, all the details are hidden from you, and manipulating the pixel data can be as simple as in this example:

```
Image my_image(); // create an *empty* image using the default Image constructor
my_image.read("picture.jpg");
my_image.pixelColor(50,50,Color("red")); // set the pixel at position (50,50) to red
my_image.write("saved_picture.jpg");
```